# What assembly has EventProgress in it for Windows Phone 7?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, async-await

I am using Task-based Asynchronous Pattern objects and methods in my Windows Phone 7 application written in C# using VS2012.  I have installed the following additional packages to facilitate this:

- Async for .NET Framework 4, Silverlight 4 (Microsoft.BCL.Async version 1.0.14-rc,  Prerelease)
- BCL Portability Pack for .NET Framework 4, Silverlight 4 (Microsoft.BCL, version 1.0.16-rc, Prerelease)
- Microsoft Build Components (Microsoft.Bcl.Build 1.0.0.-rc, Prerelease)

I am able to resolve *async, await, CancellationTokenSource, IProgress*, and most of the other TAP elements.  However, I can't find the necessary Assembly/DLL for the **EventProgress** class that implements **IProgress**.

Does anyone know how I can get **EventProgress** properly resolved in a Windows Phone 7.1 app?  I know these packages say *Prerelease* but they are the newest versions I could find.  If anyone knows of anything newer that still works for Windows Phone 7.1, please let me know).

Note, this is the article that I discovered the EventProgress class.  Unfortunately, it's not a Windows Phone 7 project:

[Progress Reporting in C# 5 Async](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/129447/Progress-Reporting-in-C-5-Async#heading0010)

Comment: That article is about an *ancient* CTP of the async feature. I'd try using [`System.Progress<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692.aspx), it seems like it has kind of sort of the API that they're using.

Comment: @millimoose - Interesting idea, but the Silverlight 4 System unit (Windows Phone 7.1) doesn't seem to have the System.Progress class.

Comment: @millimoose - There's an equivalent in Microsoft.Bcl.Async called Microsoft.Progress<>.  See Jean's answer below, the accepted answer.

Comment: Right, I'm not familiar with that backport library, I was going by what MSDN search told me.

Comment: @RobertOschler Hi - I wrote that article - a long time ago! There's an updated version for .NET 4.5 RTM on my website here: [`simplygenius.net`](http://simplygenius.net/Article/AncillaryAsyncProgress) HTH

Comment: @NicholasButler - Thanks!  I follow you on Twitter and sent you an E-mail too recently.  You have a great site.

Comment: @RobertOschler thanks - glad you like it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the `Microsoft.Progress<T>` class in assembly `Microsoft.Threading.Tasks`, which implements `IProgress<T>`. It is part of the `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` package.

Comment: Thanks!  I do have Microsoft.Threading.Tasks, Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.Phone referenced in my project.  I can see them in the project References list and they are part of the Microsoft.Bcl.Async package.  However, although I can add "using Microsoft" to my source file, if I try to add "using Microsoft.Threading.Tasks", it says the namespace Threading does not exist.  Do you know why?

Comment: A namespace is not an assembly. An assembly is not a namespace. The namespace of the `Progress` class is `Microsoft`. You can probably find it in the objet explorer.

Comment: You're right.  Forgot about that in .NET.  Been up all night programming.  I see it now, thanks!  Does Microsoft.Progress save context on construciton and restore context before the Report call like EventProgress does?